# how to fix Error environment when using reticulate with command install_miniconda()

Tags: rstudio, environment, miniconda, reticulate

I can't fix this error when I install miniconda in Windows 11 with reticulate.
Here is the message :

> reticulate::install_miniconda()
>
> - Installing Miniconda -- please wait a moment ...
> - Downloading "https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe" ...
>   trying URL 'https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe'
>   Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 74687656 bytes (71.2 MB)
>   downloaded 71.2 MB
>
> - "C:/Users/charl/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/condabin/conda.bat" "create" "--yes" "--name" "r-reticulate" "python=3.8" "numpy" "--quiet" "-c" "conda-forge"
>   Error: Error creating conda environment 'r-reticulate' [exit code 1]

Thanks if you can help me